# Is attaching dependencies to a class an appropriate way to test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, bdd

I'm struggling a bit with moving over to TDD/BDD. I have multiple methods that rely on a response from an external module in order to perform their responsibility. I would like to test these methods under different circumstances, for instance if the module responds with a data object or an error.

One way of doing this would be to attach the external module to the class/module being tested as properties and then "stubbing" it. This seems a little dirty though, because you end up with all these other modules attached to your module.

**Is this an appropriate way to be testing methods that rely on a response from an external module, or is there a better way?**

**Should I be restructuring my architecture in some way to make it more easily tested? If so how?**

Here's an example of what I mean:

**my-module.js**

```
var extMod = require('external-module');

var myMod = module.exports = function () {

  /* Do Stuff */

};
myMod.prototype.extMod = extMod;

myMod.prototype.someMethod = function () {

  this.extMod({ /* request */ }, function () {
    /* Do Stuff */
  });

};
```

**myModuleSpec.js**

*I am using Mocha, Chai, and Sinon in this example*

```
var chai       = require('chai');
var expect     = chai.expect;
var sinon      = require('sinon');
var sinonChai  = require('sinon-chai');

var myMod = require('../lib/my-module.js');

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('My Module', function () {

  /* Some Tests */

  describe('.someMethod()', function () {

    it('should do something when a data object is returned', function () {

      var foo  = new myMod();
      var stub = sinon.stub(foo, 'extMod').returns({ id: 1, name: 'Some Name' });
      var result = foo.someMethod();

      expect(result).to.be.true;

    });

    it('should do something when an error is returned', function () {

      var foo  = new myMod();
      var err = new Error('Something terrible happened.');
      var stub = sinon.stub(foo, 'extMod').returns(err);
      var result = foo.someMethod();

      expect(result).to.be.false;

    });

  });
});
```

---

### Alternative

I also considered creating a method that just returns whatever you pass to it, then running external methods through this to allow stubbing without actually attaching the external modules to the class. The only issue here is that you could only stub one external method, which is probably doable.

like this:

```
var extMod = require('external-module');

var myMod = module.exports = function () {

  /* Do Stuff */

};
myMod.prototype.extMod = function (module) {
  return module;
};

myMod.prototype.someMethod = function () {

  var extModule = this.extMod(extMod);
  extModule({ /* request */ }, function () {
    /* Do Stuff */
  });

};
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend the dependency injection pattern. Read up a great and fitting example here: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-injection-in-JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading up some more on DI. I hadn't considered the testing benefits of it. I always just considered it to be a way to keep things clean, reusable, and readable in larger projects.